# What are the best measures of market liquidity?

Tags: liquidity, liquidity-risk

Does any single metric provide a convenient way to capture depth, breadth, and resiliency, or to distinguish between transitory and persistent effects (i.e. between the stationary and random walk components of a time-series model)?

Which of the many volume-, price-, and transaction cost-based measures are most widely adopted?

I'm trying to relate observed volatility to liquidity and first need to settle on some objective measure of liquidity

Comment: for what you're trying to do it sounds like some n interval dollar volume average would be sufficient.